# flickering faded out div. How can I stop that?

Tags: jquery

sorry to annoy you with my questions today.

Do you have an idea how I can stop the div from flickering when I go to the different submenus and when I move the mouse away? 
I want the content being the whoel time on 50%. It seems that when I browse through different submenus each jump it fades in again.
What can I do?? Thanks so much for your help.

http://www.guntmarwolff.com/test/fadetest3.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){

  $("#Layer5 li a").hover( function() {
       console.log("in");
      $("#header1").fadeTo('slow', 0.5);
      }, 
  function () {
      console.log("out");
      $("#header1").fadeTo('slow', 1);
});

});
</script>
```

Comment: Press F12 in Chrome or FF with Firebug for console view. The console.log("in"); etc are for testing.

Comment: If you spend a little time reading the jquery docs you'll enjoy this much more!

Comment: I don't see any flickering.

Answer (score 0):

If the "flickering" is because of it constantly going "in and out" of fading, you *could either use .stop() or use animate and queue:false, like so -

```
$("#Layer5 li a").hover( function() {
    $("#header1").animate(
      {'opacity': '.5'},
      {queue: false}
    )
}, function () {
    $("#header1").animate(
      {'opacity': '1'},
      {queue: false}
    )
});
```

Here is a fiddle of the working example - 
http://jsfiddle.net/jmsessink/XwMVj/